# how to ssh to the remote path?

Tags: ssh

I have a folder in ~/apps/ and another one in the root /apps/

I want to ssh to them

```
ssh user@abc.com:~/apps/
```

and

```
ssh user@abc.com:/apps/
```

I got the following error:

> Could not resolve hostname

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you found a solution?

Comment: @dnl I haven't found out yet, I want to use git to push my local repo to the remote site, but I need to ssh to a path

Comment: than I suggest you should ask simple the question how to do this :) you might find your answer here: http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
ssh user@server -t "cd /some/directory; bash --login"
```

- `-t` keeps up the connection if there is user interaction)
- the "command" is in quotes
- `bash --login` is required to keep up the connection after the `cd` (see `-t`)

Comment: see comments underneath questions for more information

Comment: Its worked 100% for me. ;)

Answer (score 5):

SSH expects the following syntax:

```
ssh [other_options] [user@]hostname [command]
```

so when you typed:

```
ssh user@abc.com:~/apps/
```

SSH understood that you want to connect to a host named "abc.com:~/apps/" with a user "user". Since that host does not exist, you receive the error you quoted.

You will have to break your command into two like this:

```
ssh user@abc.com
(type the password, and wait for ssh to log you in)
cd ~/apps/
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mixing [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) and [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

For ssh you do not need to specify the destination path. You just log in as user@host.com and you land into the user's home folder.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: You can always ssh as user@abc.com and then just navigate to the desired folder using cd folderName

Ozair Kafray explained it better

Answer (score 0):

Below let me to login & go to a directory in one line, on ubuntu:

```
ssh user@abc.com -t "cd /path/to/your/directory/; `echo $SHELL --login`"
```

OR just

```
ssh user@abc.com -t "cd /path/to/your/directory/; bash --login"
```

Best of luck