# rsync doesn't work when specifying location

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, rsync, git-bash

## Edit

<strike>ssh user@192.168.0.11</strike>

<strike>Works fine, however;</strike>

<strike>ssh user@192.168.0.11:/some/location</strike>

<strike>doesn't work.</strike>

<strike>ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.0.11:/some/location: Name or service not known</strike>

*Sorry, I thought this was an ssh problem, I don't know why but I for some reason I thought you could ssh into a folder like that. Turns out it is an rsync problem.*

I am getting a weird rsync error

```
rsync -navz -e ssh win10/data user@192.168.0.11
```

would work, but when I tried specifying a target directory on my Ubuntu server, it would

`rsync -navz -e ssh win10/data user@192.168.0.11:/some/location`

```
dup() in/out/err failed

rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at 
/usr/src/rsync/rsync-3.0.8/io.c(760) [sender=3.0.8]
```

I think it might be related to the fact I am using git bash on the local win10 box.  I installed rsync from MinGW and added

```
PATH=$PATH:/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin
```

to my .bash_profile to get rsync to work.

Also **scp example.pdf user@192.168.0.11:/some/location**
works just fine so its definitely rsync.

Comment: You're using the wrong way to specify the path. `host:port` with a port being a path isn't going to work.

Comment: You're confusing rsync with ssh. https://superuser.com/a/250538/39436

Comment: @quadruplebucky I tried it with quoting and without the -e ssh switch, still same error.

Comment: Googling your error message indicates you're not alone, it's dedinitely a cygwin/rsync interaction.  Some report sucess resinstalling rsync.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong syntax:

```
SYNOPSIS
     ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
[-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L address] [-l
login_name]
         [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w
local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

Note that when specifying the `hostname`, only the `user@` may be optionally specified. The `ssh` command just establishes SSH connections to the remote host. If you want to upload files, you can use the SCP protocol using the `scp` or `rsync` commands which have the syntax you specified.